# are nested vector allocated in consecutive space

Tags: c++, performance, memory, vector, stl

For example, the following code creates 1000000 vector, each of them has length of 10.

After that we may sequentially scan the vector several times. If the 2nd-layer vectors are allocated in consecutive space( may few 2nd-layer vectors can fit in a cache block), the following access are efficient. But, if the 2nd-layer vectors are allocated in different places, each time we leave the inner loop we may jump to a random places to get the data, which is not efficient.

`vector<vector<int > > a(1000000 , vector<int>(10))`

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
{
     for (int j = 0; j< a[i].size() ; j++) {
         a[i][j]++;
     }
}
```

Furthermore, if the 2nd-layer vectors are allocated in consecutive space at first. After we push_back elements into vectors, they may be moved to other space due to the lack of space to extent them in-place. Will they still be kept in nearby?

Thank you.

**EDIT1**

Thanks, is there any implementation that put them together for improving performance of sequential scanning ?

Answer (score 3):

`vector<int>` is just a small controller class, typically three words long. The actual managed dynamic memory is, well, allocated dynamically, so it is in essentially random locations. Your outer vector manages a contiguous range of inner vectors, but each inner vector manages an unrelated range of ints.

If you want contiguous storage, consider a single `vector<int>` of size 1000000 × 10 and access it in strides.

Comment: thanks, is there any implementation that put them together for improving performance of sequential scanning ?

Comment: @SiNZeRo.wentt: I described that implementation in my answer :-S

Answer (score 0):

> are nested vector allocated in consecutive space?

No! The space allocated from the inner vectors will not be guaranteed to be consecutive! Only the vector instances themselves will appear in a consecutive memory section managed by the outer vector.

Comment: It might be consecutive, and it sometimes is (nearly) consecutive on common implementations.  But your general point stands.

Comment: @tmyklebu I know that inner vectors are not allocated in consecutive spaces, but their point are stored together.  Do you have any reference that shows they are probably stores nearly for efficiency by some implementations.

Comment: @SiNZeRo.wentt You may provide a specialized allocator as 2nd template parameter for the outer vector to do so.